# Excel macro search ends in error when nothing found

Tags: excel, vba

My Case 1 excel macro code runs as long as data is being found by the search but bombs with the stated error when there is nothing in the search result.  So I tried putting in a "set" see Case 2... but that Case bombs on any search.

CASE 1:  Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

```
 Cells.Find(What:=sCurrentISOtext & "_", After:=ActiveCell, _
            LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt :=xlWhole , _
           SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:= False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

CASE 2: Run-time error '424': Object required

```
  Dim c As Range 

  Set c = Cells.Find(What:=sCurrentISOtext & "_", After:=ActiveCell, _
                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt :=xlWhole, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                     MatchCase:= False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

You mean like this?? It still fails.

CASE 3: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

```
Dim c As Range      

c = Cells.Find(What:=sCurrentISOtext & "_", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole = 0, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
        :=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not c Is Nothing Then   
    c.Activate     
    ' and do something here < > 
End If
```

Comment: You mean like this??  It still fails.

CASE 3: Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Dim c As Range   

c = Cells.Find(What:=sCurrentISOtext & "_", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole = 0, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase _
        :=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        
If Not c Is Nothing Then               
c.Activate                                 
'   and do something here <    >
  End If

Comment: **tldr:** you cannot FindNext if you redefine the Find operation in the interim.

Comment: If you insist on obfuscating your question then the comments become no more the a game of 20 Questions. [edit] your question to include these clarifications.

Answer (score 4):

This would naturally fail, you are calling  "activate" on a null (failed) result - so there's nothing to activate at runtime. You have to wrap in an If statement -

```
Dim c As Range

Set c = Cells.Find(What:=sCurrentISOtext & "_", _
                   After:=ActiveCell, _
                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   LookAt:=xlWhole = 0, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:= False, _
                   SearchFormat:=False)

If c Is Nothing Then
    'do something
Else
    c.Activate
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an ugly work around that I use when I'm in a hurry -- there are more elegant error traps, but this gets it done.

```
On Error GoTo notFound
Dim c As Range

Set c = Cells.Find(What:=sCurrentISOtext & "_", _
                   After:=ActiveCell, _
                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                   LookAt:=xlWhole = 0, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=False, _
                   SearchFormat:=False)
c.Activate
Exit Sub

notFound:

Application.InputBox "Could not find the range you wanted." 
' >> You can put in whatever action you want here -- for example,        <<
' >> if you're using this as a module, then "Exit Sub" or "Goto nextOne" <<
' >> could be used go to the next step in your process.                  <<
```

Comment: Consider reformatting your answer, it is hard to understand what you mean. Use the tools provided such as the `{ }` icon to denote code.